# Defer parsing of JavaScript in rails 3.1 with nginx and unicorn

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails 3.1 + nginx + unicorn in linode vps with 512 mb ram and ubuntu 10.04 64bits and Mongodb for my project.

I get a alert in google pagespeed in my production server, such as you can see in the next image:

[image]

I have assets precompiled and works fine.

Then my question is:

**how can I remove this alert in my project rails 3.1?**

Thank you!

Comment: You have several methods here. `First` You can use asynchronous script loading to keep scripts from blocking the page load. `Second` You can simply move all functions that you _do not need at the time of page load_ and put them in a window.onLoad function or ($(document).ready(function(){ in jQuery))

Comment: thank you, can you write a code example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code that does not need to be loaded at the time of the page load can be loaded after using jQuery, or JavaScript. I'll show you both

javascript:

```
window.onLoad = function(){ //defers js to load on window ready }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //defers js to load on document ready

});
```

You can use either of those methods.

For Asynchronous Script loading, you can google it and get thousands of examples.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be worth setting this up unless profiling of the page load suggests that it is particularly slow.

You should already have the javascript tag located at the bottom of the page instead of the head, and (as stated in the other answer) any code that should wait until the DOM is ready inside a ready block.

This will ensure that the page will load first along with the CSS, and can start rendering while the JS downloads and runs.

Deferring parsing is most useful when you have a large number of functions attached to the page which are for user interaction, and are not required to render the page.

More details [are here](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#DeferLoadingJS).